# MagicalRecord - Retrieve the last inserted record id

Tags: ios, objective-c, magicalrecord

I'm using MagicalRecord and I can not understand with and retrieve the id of the record you just saved

```
Items *item = [Items MR_createEntity];
item.ref_user = ref_user;
[self saveContext];



- (void)saveContext {
    [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        if (success) {
            DDLogInfo(@"MR_saveContext success");
            [self loadView];
            [self viewDidLoad];
        } else if (error) {
            DDLogError(@"Error saving context: %@", error.description);
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: So... what's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just create it out of block?

```
item = [ITEM MR_createEntityInContext:defaultContext];
[defaultContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];

// you can retrieve the id of above item here
```